# Spinner opens from top and not from bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, spinner

[You can perfectly see the problem here, the drop downlist opens from the top of the spinner and not from the bottom and I don't know what to do, couldn't find any solution on google either, please help me] sorry for external image link, for some reason it wont load the picture here..

[image]

here is my spinner code:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/rgGender"
android:entries="@array/months_array"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:id="@+id/spMonth"
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This would happen if the item which inflates the spinner is close to the bottom of the screen.**

Since the spinner would not have enough room (or just barely enough room) if inflated downward, it is inflated upward instead. Try putting the spinner higher (vertically) in the layout.

It depends on **Screen size**, If you test it on other device it will show at down/up.

I suggest you to test it on different devices.

you can use custome adapter if you want

```
<Spinner
...
android:overlapAnchor="false" />
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647299/android-spinner-with-different-layouts-for-drop-down-state-and-closed-state) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773105/how-to-let-the-spinner-items-appear-below-itself-when-being-clicked-and-with-ful)

Comment: tell me if still in confusion.@shay mishali

Comment: that was my first thought then I created an adaptor to make it smaller and still it poped out from the top while clearly it had enough room to go lower. the overlap did fix the problem but how about changing the height of the dropdown list? so it will be smaller and then it will appear the same on all screens but you will just have to scroll.

Comment: Nop. It will adjust as per device that is not an issue.

Comment: i want to make the size of the drop down 80dp, is it possible?

Comment: ok, i don't mind, I just want it to have a normal size, it's ugly when it opens the whole list. please tell me how to do that

Comment: Use wrap_content and give padding 5dp

Comment: use custom adapter describe in link