# How to correctly show a popup menu below a TextView, similar to Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-popupwindow

### Background

I had to create a spinner-like view, which has this behavior:

- textView that has the selected item text in it, with an arrow icon on the right that indicates whether it's in "open" state.
- upon clicking the view, a popup menu appears below it (not on top), showing a list of items to choose from, and has the selected item marked as well.
- around the popupWindow, there is a semi-transparent black color.
- has a customized animation for opening and closing it.

### The problem

I have succeeded making this view (code below), but for some reason, on Android 7.1, I got the popup menu to appear on top of the view (even overlapping it and views above it), instead of below it, as it should. Here's how it looks like, vs how it should look like:

[image]

Since it's quite a lot of code and resources, I've put it all in a Github repository ([**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/FullSizePopupSpinner)), but here's the main part of the code (my tries of fixing it are in comments) :

**FullSizePopupSpinner.java**

```
public class FullSizePopupSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 150;
    private int[] mItemsTextsResIds, mItemsIconsResIds;
    private int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;
    private SpinnerPopupWindow mPopupWindow;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelectedListener;
    private Drawable mClosedDrawable;
    private Drawable mOpenedDrawable;

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onItemSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner parent, int position, String item, int previousSelectedPosition);

        void onNothingSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner parent);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.mSelectedItemPosition = this.mSelectedItemPosition;
        ss.mItemsTextsResIds = mItemsTextsResIds;
        ss.mItemsIconsResIds = mItemsIconsResIds;
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setItems(ss.mItemsTextsResIds, ss.mItemsIconsResIds);
        setSelectedItemPosition(ss.mSelectedItemPosition);
    }

    public void setItems(final int[] itemsTextsResIds, final int[] itemsIconsResIds) {
        mItemsTextsResIds = itemsTextsResIds;
        mItemsIconsResIds = itemsIconsResIds;
        if (mItemsTextsResIds != null && mSelectedItemPosition >= 0 && mSelectedItemPosition < mItemsTextsResIds.length)
            setText(mItemsTextsResIds[mSelectedItemPosition]);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(this, null, null, isPopupShown() ? mOpenedDrawable : mClosedDrawable, null);
    }

    public boolean isPopupShown() {
        return mPopupWindow != null && mPopupWindow.isShowing();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return mSelectedItemPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemPosition(final int selectedItemPosition) {
        int lastSelectedItemPosition = mSelectedItemPosition;
        mSelectedItemPosition = selectedItemPosition;
        final String itemText = mItemsTextsResIds != null && mSelectedItemPosition >= 0 && mSelectedItemPosition < mItemsTextsResIds.length ?
                getResources().getString(mItemsTextsResIds[mSelectedItemPosition]) : null;
        setText(itemText);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);
        if (mOnItemSelectedListener != null)
            mOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, selectedItemPosition, itemText, lastSelectedItemPosition);
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener) {
        mOnItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mPopupWindow != null)
            mPopupWindow.dismissRightAway();
    }

    protected void init(final Context context) {
        if (mInitialized)
            return;
        mInitialized = true;
        setSaveEnabled(true);
        mClosedDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_arrow_down, null);
        mOpenedDrawable = ViewUtil.getRotateDrawable(mClosedDrawable, 180);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (mItemsTextsResIds == null)
                    return;
                if (mPopupWindow != null)
                    mPopupWindow.dismissRightAway();
                TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mOpenedDrawable, null);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_popup, null, false);
                final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__itemsContainer);
                final View overlayView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__overlay);
                linearLayout.setPivotY(0);
                linearLayout.setScaleY(0);
                linearLayout.animate().scaleY(1).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                mPopupWindow = new SpinnerPopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true, overlayView, linearLayout);
                mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                mPopupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
                //PopupWindowCompat.setOverlapAnchor(mPopupWindow, false);
                //if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M)
                //    mPopupWindow.setOverlapAnchor(false);
                final AtomicBoolean isItemSelected = new AtomicBoolean(false);
                if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__preLollipopShadow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFffffff);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mItemsTextsResIds.length; ++i) {
                    final String itemText = getResources().getString(mItemsTextsResIds[i]);
                    final int position = i;
                    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_popup_item, linearLayout, false);
                    final TextView textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    textView.setText(itemText);
                    if (mItemsIconsResIds != null)
                        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(textView, mItemsIconsResIds[position], 0,
                                position == mSelectedItemPosition ? R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_v : 0, 0);
                    else
                        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(textView, 0, 0, position == mSelectedItemPosition ? R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_v : 0, 0);

                    linearLayout.addView(itemView, linearLayout.getChildCount() - 2);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            isItemSelected.set(true);
                            mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                            setSelectedItemPosition(position);
                        }
                    });
                }
                overlayView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                overlayView.setAlpha(0);
                overlayView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                mPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss() {
                        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);
                        if (!isItemSelected.get() && mOnItemSelectedListener != null)
                            mOnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner.this);
                    }
                });
                // optional: set animation style. look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9648797/878126
                mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(0);
                //PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(mPopupWindow, v, 0, 0, Gravity.TOP);
                //mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0, Gravity.TOP);
                mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    static class SpinnerPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {
        private final View mOverlayView;
        private final View mLayout;

        public SpinnerPopupWindow(final View contentView, final int width, final int height, final boolean focusable, View overlayView, View layout) {
            super(contentView, width, height, focusable);
            mOverlayView = overlayView;
            mLayout = layout;
        }

        public void dismissRightAway() {
            super.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void dismiss() {
            final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = mOverlayView.animate().alpha(0);
            mLayout.setPivotY(0);
            mLayout.animate().scaleY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
            ViewUtil.runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dismissRightAway();
                }
            });
            animator.start();
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////
    //SavedState//
    //////////////
    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        private int[] mItemsTextsResIds;
        private int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;
        public int[] mItemsIconsResIds;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(@NonNull Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            this.mItemsTextsResIds = in.createIntArray();
            mSelectedItemPosition = in.readInt();
            mItemsIconsResIds = in.createIntArray();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeIntArray(mItemsTextsResIds);
            out.writeInt(mSelectedItemPosition);
            out.writeIntArray(mItemsIconsResIds);
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Creator<SavedState>() {
                    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SavedState(in);
                    }

                    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }
}
```

### What I've tried

I tried calling the next functions (and combinations), but none helped:

- mPopupWindow.setOverlapAnchor(false);
- PopupWindowCompat.setOverlapAnchor(mPopupWindow,false);
- mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM);
- PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(mPopupWindow,v, 0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM);
- mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0, Gravity.TOP);
- PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(mPopupWindow,v, 0, 0, Gravity.TOP);

### The question

Why does the popup window appear on top of the view? How can I avoid this, and still have the window below the view, as was done before?

Is there maybe a bug on Android 7.1 , which causes this behavior? How can I overcome this?

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973893/android-nougat-7-1-1-howatlocation-gravity-not-working), and the link to the issue there.

Comment: @MikeM. It shows a workaround, but as I tried (and written there), it doesn't work on 7.1.1 .

Comment: I was mainly bringing it to your attention for the bug report link, but I had also noticed that you didn't mention trying `showAtLocation()` (not that that seems to work, either), so it was just a heads up, really.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I've decided to post a bug report : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233237

Comment: perhaps the textview is larger than it looks (goes behind the toolbar). and hence it's top is the top of the screen

Comment: @howdoidothis The textView is fine. Run the sample (even the original one). Only after clicking it, the popup window gets more space than it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've fixed it by changing the layout and its code, but I still don't get why the code didn't work well on Android 7.1.1, yet worked fine on older versions.

Here is the current code (updated github repository too, original code with the issue can be found [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233237)) :

**ViewUtil.java**

```
class ViewUtil {
    static Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Drawable d, final int angle) {
        return new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{d}) {
            @Override
            public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.save();
                canvas.rotate(angle, d.getBounds().width() / 2, d.getBounds().height() / 2);
                super.draw(canvas);
                canvas.restore();
            }
        };
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    static ViewPropertyAnimator runOnAnimationEnd(final ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Runnable runnable) {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            animator.withEndAction(runnable);
        else
            animator.setListener(new android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
                    animator.setListener(null);
                    runnable.run();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
                }
            });
        return animator;
    }
}
```

**FullSizePopupSpinner.java**

```
public class FullSizePopupSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 150;
    private int[] mItemsTextsResIds, mItemsIconsResIds;
    private int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;
    private SpinnerPopupWindow mPopupWindow;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelectedListener;
    private Drawable mClosedDrawable;
    private Drawable mOpenedDrawable;

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onItemSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner parent, int position, String item, int previousSelectedPosition);

        void onNothingSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner parent);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public FullSizePopupSpinner(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.mSelectedItemPosition = this.mSelectedItemPosition;
        ss.mItemsTextsResIds = mItemsTextsResIds;
        ss.mItemsIconsResIds = mItemsIconsResIds;
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setItems(ss.mItemsTextsResIds, ss.mItemsIconsResIds);
        setSelectedItemPosition(ss.mSelectedItemPosition);
    }

    public void setItems(final int[] itemsTextsResIds, final int[] itemsIconsResIds) {
        mItemsTextsResIds = itemsTextsResIds;
        mItemsIconsResIds = itemsIconsResIds;
        if (mItemsTextsResIds != null && mSelectedItemPosition >= 0 && mSelectedItemPosition < mItemsTextsResIds.length)
            setText(mItemsTextsResIds[mSelectedItemPosition]);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(this, null, null, isPopupShown() ? mOpenedDrawable : mClosedDrawable, null);
    }

    public boolean isPopupShown() {
        return mPopupWindow != null && mPopupWindow.isShowing();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return mSelectedItemPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemPosition(final int selectedItemPosition) {
        int lastSelectedItemPosition = mSelectedItemPosition;
        mSelectedItemPosition = selectedItemPosition;
        final String itemText = mItemsTextsResIds != null && mSelectedItemPosition >= 0 && mSelectedItemPosition < mItemsTextsResIds.length ?
                getResources().getString(mItemsTextsResIds[mSelectedItemPosition]) : null;
        setText(itemText);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);
        if (mOnItemSelectedListener != null)
            mOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, selectedItemPosition, itemText, lastSelectedItemPosition);
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener) {
        mOnItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mPopupWindow != null)
            mPopupWindow.dismissRightAway();
    }

    protected void init(final Context context) {
        if (mInitialized)
            return;
        mInitialized = true;
        setSaveEnabled(true);
        mClosedDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_arrow_down, null);
        mOpenedDrawable = ViewUtil.getRotateDrawable(mClosedDrawable, 180);
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (mItemsTextsResIds == null)
                    return;
                if (mPopupWindow != null)
                    mPopupWindow.dismissRightAway();
                TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mOpenedDrawable, null);
                final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_popup, null, false);
                final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__recyclerView);
                final View overlayView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__overlay);
                final View itemsContainer = popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__itemsContainer);
                itemsContainer.setPivotY(0);
                itemsContainer.setScaleY(0);
                itemsContainer.animate().scaleY(1).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                mPopupWindow = new SpinnerPopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true, overlayView,
                        itemsContainer);
                mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                mPopupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
                final AtomicBoolean isItemSelected = new AtomicBoolean(false);
                if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_drop_down_popup__preLollipopShadow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFffffff);
                }
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter() {
                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
                        final View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_popup_item, recyclerView, false);
                        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView) {
                        };
                        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final View v) {
                                isItemSelected.set(true);
                                mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                                setSelectedItemPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                            }
                        });
                        return holder;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                        final String itemText = getResources().getString(mItemsTextsResIds[position]);
                        final TextView textView = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        textView.setText(itemText);
                        if (mItemsIconsResIds != null)
                            TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(textView, mItemsIconsResIds[position], 0,
                                    position == mSelectedItemPosition ? R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_v : 0, 0);
                        else
                            TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(textView, 0, 0, position == mSelectedItemPosition ? R.drawable.drop_down_menu_ic_v : 0, 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getItemCount() {
                        return mItemsTextsResIds.length;
                    }
                });
                overlayView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                overlayView.setAlpha(0);
                overlayView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                mPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss() {
                        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(FullSizePopupSpinner.this, null, null, mClosedDrawable, null);
                        if (!isItemSelected.get() && mOnItemSelectedListener != null)
                            mOnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(FullSizePopupSpinner.this);
                    }
                });
                // optional: set animation style. look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9648797/878126
                mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(0);
                PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(mPopupWindow, v, 0, 0, Gravity.TOP);
            }
        });

    }

    static class SpinnerPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {
        private final View mOverlayView;
        private final View mLayout;

        public SpinnerPopupWindow(final View contentView, final int width, final int height, final boolean focusable, View overlayView, View layout) {
            super(contentView, width, height, focusable);
            mOverlayView = overlayView;
            mLayout = layout;
        }

        public void dismissRightAway() {
            super.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void dismiss() {
            final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = mOverlayView.animate().alpha(0);
            mLayout.setPivotY(0);
            mLayout.animate().scaleY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
            ViewUtil.runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dismissRightAway();
                }
            });
            animator.start();
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////
    //SavedState//
    //////////////
    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        private int[] mItemsTextsResIds;
        private int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;
        public int[] mItemsIconsResIds;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(@NonNull Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            this.mItemsTextsResIds = in.createIntArray();
            mSelectedItemPosition = in.readInt();
            mItemsIconsResIds = in.createIntArray();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeIntArray(mItemsTextsResIds);
            out.writeInt(mSelectedItemPosition);
            out.writeIntArray(mItemsIconsResIds);
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Creator<SavedState>() {
                    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SavedState(in);
                    }

                    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }
}
```

**spinner_drop_down_popup.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/spinner_drop_down_popup__overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33000000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_drop_down_popup__itemsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/spinner_drop_down_popup__recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_view_horizontal_divider"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinner_drop_down_popup__preLollipopShadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using PopupWindow and try to use `android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow` instead.

Also one of the first things to check with such a problems is targetSdk and appCompat library version are up to date and correspond to the version of android you are trying to run your application on.

Comment: I tried to update all to latest version but it didn't help. About ListPopupWindow, I don't think it can be as customized as I wanted on this case. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it for the same purpose and if I set up anchorView and define gravity it works fine on all versions from API 16 to 25. What type of customization you want that absent for ListPopupWindow?

Comment: Try the code on old Android versions and see what I try to achieve. Also look at what I've looked for. The popup should be below, having a dark background around, and with animation of being opened/closed.